# Find the index of the last opened Bloomberg window

Tags: c#, bloomberg, dde

I'm opening a Bloomberg equity page using the standard DDE string

```
<blp-1><home>MSFT US<EQUITY><GO>DES<GO>
```

I have a requirement from the trading desk to default the display window of the equity to the last opened Bloomberg window. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.  We allow the traders to set a preference (windows 1,2,3,4 = blp-0, blp-1, blp-2, blp-3) then you just need to convince them to get used to using 3 instead of 4 windows for their day to day usage.